# Oracle listener not responding with its IP Address

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I come here today after spending two days trying figure out what happened to my oracle server. Here is the situation:
I am running windows server 2016 on a EC2 instance (Amazon AWS). This server is something like a server to test my application running with Oracle, so I basically have my ASP.Net application running on IIS and a Oracle database.

Sometimes I need to connect remotely to this server in order to debug my application with Visual Studio. Therefore, I have oracle client instaled in my machine in order to do this remote connection.

Everything was working just fine until a few weeks ago. Suddenly something happened and I couln't connect remotely anymore. After trying for hours, I decided terminate de EC2 instance and install everything again.

I did that, and now I am facing kind of the same issue. I will post a print screen here, and right after I'll tell what I have tested so far.

[image]

**Here is the content of the sqlnet.ora file:**

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

---

***Here is the content of the listener.ora file:***

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Administrator\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\Administrator\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ***ipaddress***)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

---

***Here is the content of the tsnames.ora file:***

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ***ipaddress***)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = xe)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ***ipaddress***)(PORT = 1521))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

---

My observations:

- I don't think this is a firewall issue since the print screen above shows a test inside the server.
- **I am getting this error "ORA 12 541 TNS: no listener" when I try to connect to Oracle from my machine.**
- If I try TELNET on port 23 the server responds, but it does not if I try Telnet on 1521 (tried it with the firewall down)
- I have configured already the security group on Amazon AWS to accept all trafic
- **The application running in this same server is still able to connect to Oracle, so I guess I can't say the listener is down.**
- I ran the command "lsnrctl status" to see if the listener is running:
  [image]
- This is when I run the command "lsnrctl start":
  [image]

Comment: Have you tried `$lsnrctl status` and `$lsnrctl start`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that @BarbarosÖzhan . Here is what windows when I try "lsnrctl start" "Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started"   I will add an print screen to the post showing the result when I try "lsnrctl status"

Comment: excuse me but the links didn't work on my screen.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan when I type "lsnrctl status" the first thing I am getting is this error: "TNS 12541: TNS no listener"

Comment: we can still see 127.0.0.1 in your lsnrctl status output, are you sure you changed it and restarted the listener? and try tnsping XE.
it is not valid to use a hostname or ipadress using tnsping, you should use a valid connect EZCONNECT syntax or a tnsnames.ora alias

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO I have tried that, but still the same. TNSPing XE  works, oracle responds OK to that. However, still I can't connect remotely.

Comment: How do you connect to your database, can you share your connection string?

Comment: Here is the connection string @CyrilleMODIANO XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = IPADDRESS)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO  I am starting to see something odd here. I found this video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCKIAle_i74  it says bitness matters when talking about Oracle Provider. I tested the provider 64bits, and it worked! I didn't work when I tried the 32bits, it returns me a message: "ORA 28040: No matching authentication protocol". That is the same message I am getting right now from my ASP.Net Application. Would them be related?

Comment: it is always recommended to use 64 bits driver if you use a 64 bits database, why don't you use the 64 bits if it works?

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO How can I make Visual Studio use the 64bits driver instead of the 32bits? I'll try to unistall the 32bits and see if it looks for the 64 bits driver.

Comment: what driver are you using? ODP.net?

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO I'm using oracle client. After installing it, I open a file.UDL, it gives me a list of the providers. I am testing the provider called "Oracle Provider for OLE DB". The test works for the UDL 64bits, but it does not for the 32bits. My ASP.Net application returns the same error when I test the 32bit UDL file.

Comment: I strongly advise you to use ODP.net when you work with oracle which provides better performance and better handling of oracle advanced features. You can download it fron here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index-090165.html
Then you will need to add a reference in you ASP.net project to be able to use it.

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO I removed all oracle clients I had in my machine. After that I downloaded ODP.net from the link you sent, and installed again. The provider responds just fine (testing through an UDL file). However, when I try to connect to Oracle through my ASP.Net application it says there is no Oracle Provider. My guess is that my application only looks for a Oracle Provider 32bits. I am afraid If I download it, I'll get that same error "ORA 28040 again"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was not related to any of that things I mentioned.
I openend "Services (services.msc)" and figure there was a Oracle dbconsole service down. I tried to start it, but another error came up. The error was about a folder that Oracle was looking for. Oracle was looking for a folder that was named with the ipaddress plus the service name, something like "*/192.168.0.1_XE/*"
. However, I checked the path to get to this folder, and I had "*/localhost_XE/*".

- Therefore, to solve this, I simply created a new folder, copied the files from the localhost folder, and pasted in this new one that was named with the IP Address. After that I was able to start the service and everything went back to normal.
- The was another thing I did, but I'm not sure if that also helped with the issue. I changed the ipaddress in the "listener.ora" file to "*0.0.0.0*"